# Mongoid embeds_many validation error message is plural_objects + "is invalid"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

```
class Report
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :figures
end

class Figure
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :report
  field :legend
  validates_presence_of :legend
end
```

Yields this error message:

```
Figures is invalid
```

How can I get the plurality in the error message to agree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The translation from errors into readable messages is handled by ActiveModel rather than Mongoid, and embedded models are considered to just be attributes in terms of attribute localization.

In this case, if you use the below in an i18n file you'll get a singular form rather than plural by modifying what `human_attribute_name` returns for the figures attribute:

```
en:
    mongoid:
        attributes:
            report:
                figures: Figure
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Mongoid docs](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations.html):

> You can name your relations whatever you like, but if the class cannot
>   be inferred by Mongoid from the name, and neither can the opposite
>   side you'll want to provide the macro with some additional options to
>   tell Mongoid how to hook them up.

You should just have to use

```
class Report
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :figures, class_name: "Figure"
end

class Figure
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :report, class_name: "Report"
  field :legend
  validates_presence_of :legend
end
```

Comment: You answer looked good until I tried it and it doesn't work. Mongoid should be able to infer common "s" suffix plurals. That part works fine with or without specifying the class name. The problem remains in the validation message.